# Switching jPanels in Java from external class

Tags: java, containers, jframe, jpanel, switch-statement

I have `jFrame` class `MainForm` which contains `main()`, `placePanel(panel)` and drop down menu. From the items in drop down menu I call on `placePanel(panel)` method to place a specific panel in the `jFrame` container. This works fine.

But, I don't know how to switch panels when I click on a button which is inside a `jPanel` class. When I try to call `jFrame`'s `MainForm.placePanel(panel)` from any `jPanel` which is loaded into `jFrame`'s container, I get the error: `cannot reference non-static content` etc. I also tried `Mainform.getContainer().add(panel)`, but it doesn't work too.

I can't figure out how to access `MainForm`'s container from another class, or how to switch panels with a method from another panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a method on an object from within another object, you're going to need a reference to the first object so you can call the method on the active object itself and not on the class (as you're currently trying to do).  One way to solve this is to pass a reference to the class that holds the JPanels to the class that has the button's action listener code, perhaps in the latter's constructor.  In other words you'll want to pass a reference to the current active and visualized MainForm object into the class that has the ActionListener for the button.

By the way, are you swapping JPanels with a CardLayout? If not, I suggest you look into it as it's usually the easiest way to do this.

Edit:

For example, say you have a class called MainForm that has a public method called swapJPanels that allows it to swap views, and another class MyPanel that has your JButton that wants to call a method from the MainForm class, then you could give MyPanel a constructor that takes a MainForm parameter and allows you to pass a reference from the current MainForm object (this inside of the class), into the MyPanel object:

MainForm:

```
class MainForm extends JFrame { 

   public MainForm() {
      MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(this); // pass "this" or the current MainForm reference to MyPanel
   }

   public void swapJPanels(int panelNumber) {

   }
}
```

MyPanel:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private MainForm myMainForm; // holds the reference to the current MainForm object

   public MyPanel(MainForm myMainForm) {
      this.myMainForm = myMainForm; // set the reference

      JButton swapPanelBtn = new JButton("Swap Panel");
      swapPanelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            swapPanelBtnActionPerformed();
         }
      });
   }

   private void swapPanelBtnActionPerformed() {
      myMainForm.swapJPanels(0); // calling a method on the reference to the current MainForm object
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using cardLayout, I don't know anything about and this is the first time I heard about it. I'm going to look it up and see what it does.

Also, what do you mean by "pass a reference"? I already tried to reference jFrame' MainForm from jPanel using: MainForm.getContainer().add(panel)? This is wrong I know, but how do I correctly "pass a reference"?

Comment: @Luka: you can find a tutorial on how to use it here: [How to use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html),but understand that it won't solve your initial problem -- having and calling methods on a reference to one object inside of another object.

Comment: Ok, card layout is interesting but its a workaround. But what am I doing wrong with MainForm.getContainer().add(panel) or MainForm.placePanel(panel)? Whenever I try using this code (that works inside Jframe) from jPanel it gets errored. I already have placePanel method, how do I call it from another class?

Comment: @Luka: **Again** you're trying to call a method on the class, MainForm, and this simply won't work. You need to call the method on the MainForm **object** .  If you don't understand the difference, you should probably step back from gui coding til you have a firm grasp on the basics. These tutorials can help you: [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Comment: Your latter post is somehow more clearer to me now, thanks :) As I get it, object is the class's instance. If I want to call on the MainForm object, what do I need to do: new MainForm? I think I did that but it popped out a new MainForm, so I had 2 of them...

Comment: @Luka: No, new MainForm() will create a MainForm object that is completely distinct and independent from the MainForm that is being displayed. Again, you need to pass references. Please see the edit to my answer above.