# Java GUI using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a problem with writing things using `.setText` in a textfield if I am writing this command in code of a `Frame` in order to set text in `TextField` in another frame where as we all know that the `TextFields` in Netbeans preloaded GUI have **private method**. Any suggestions to overcome this problem

the code where I am calling the other frame to write something in it,

```
private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                          

    Tx_Customize l= new Tx_Customize();
   env_region = jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex(); 
   l.LF();
   System.out.println(env_region);

}
```

where the other frame is

```
public void LF(){
    envi = S.env_region;
    System.out.println(envi);
     switch (envi)
            {
                case 1: 
                    Penetration.setText("21.5"); 
                    LNF.setText("10");
                    System.out.println("error1");
                    break;`  


                case 0: 
                    Penetration.setText("16.5"); 
                    LNF.setText("8");
                    System.out.println("error0");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Penetration.setText("11"); 
                    LNF.setText("6");
                    System.out.println("error2");
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    Penetration.setText("7"); 
                    LNF.setText("6");
                    System.out.println("error3");
                    break;

                default : System.out.println("error");break;

            }
}
```

Comment: so where is the code that has been tried

Comment: So what problems are you having with this code? Please try to ask a complete question. It can be quite frustrating for you and us to have to try to drag information out of you bit by bit.

Comment: i have a added a code as you questioned sorry but this is my first question on stack over flow

Comment: okay as you can see in the 2nd code the switch case ...the code enters it  but actually didn't wirte anything in the textfields "penetration and LNF" which are in the 2nd frame however it display the System.out.println("error") in whatever the case i choose from the combo box in the first frame ...and i think because these are private in the preloaded code so do you know a way to make these fields are public or a way to update these fields

Comment: also i have a button is called Default which do the same switch but it presents in the same frame when i press it the values are written in the fields

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with general OOPs practices and Java: If you need to allow one class to be able to change the state of a 2nd class, give the 2nd class public methods that objects of the first class can call. This can include wrapper methods if need be that call private methods.

For a more detailed answer, then you must ask a more detailed question, one that includes pertinent code.

---

**Edit**  Regarding your comment:

> .the code enters it but actually didn't wirte anything in the textfields "penetration and LNF" which are in the 2nd frame however it display the System.out.println("error") in whatever the case i choose from the combo box in the first frame ...and i think because these are private in the preloaded code so do you know a way to

Nah, this has absolutely nothing to do with public or private and all to do with a bug in your code. If it were an access issue, your code wouldn't compile. Your problem is likely here:

```
private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                          
   Tx_Customize l= new Tx_Customize(); // *********
   env_region = jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex(); 
   l.LF();
   System.out.println(env_region);
}
```

You're creating a completely new Tx_Customize, calling methods on it, and expecting this to magically change likely another Tx_Customize object, one that is displayed, and Java doesn't work this way -- there is no magic. If you want to change the state of the displayed Tx_Customize object, then you must call methods on this very same object, not some new Tx_Customize that you create in this method.

---

**Edit 2**

Other general problems:

- Your program should only have one main JFrame.
- If you absolutely need to display another window that is secondary to the first, it should be a dialog such as a JDialog.
- You are new to Swing, and because of this, should not use a Swing code generator as it is hampering your ability to learn how the library works. Instead code your Swing by hand, using the tutorials.
- You will want to study basic Java as well, to learn about the building blocks of the language, how objects work, how they're different from variables, etc. Go through an intro to Java text book or tutorial as it will help you immensely. It helped me.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventions including giving classes names that begin with an upper case letter and methods and variables names that begin with a lower case letter. This matters when you want others (us!!) to understand your code.

---

**Edit 3**
You state:

> so you mean that i should call the LF method by : Tx_Customize.LF();

Heck no. That would require that the method be static. I am suggesting that you somehow get a reference to the actual displayed other object and call the method off of that. How you get that reference will depend on a lot of things including code you've not shown us.

---

**Edit 4**
You ask:

> i want to ask a question @HoverCraftFullOfEels what is the main use of the reference because it is the first time for me to hear about it

Your problem (I believe -- but I can't say for sure as we've only seen limited code) is due to your having more than one Tx_Customize object in existence. I'm guessing that Tx_Customize extends JFrame, and that you've got one of these that you're displaying. Then in your jComboBox2ActionPerformed method you create a second Tx_Customize instance and try to call methods on it, but this will have no effect on the original Tx_Customize object. Instead you must call a method on the actual displayed Tx_Customize object.

Please understand that a variable is not the same thing as an object, and that reference (non-primitive) variables can only *refer* to objects. This is the *reference* that I'm referring to. You need the variable that you're calling `LF()` on (although you should really re-name this method) to refer to the actual displayed Tx_Customize object.

To do this, the class that holds your jComboBox2ActionPerformed method must have a variable that refers to the displayed Tx_Customize. Again, please see my answer to a similar type of question which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5693974/522444), that shows an example just this, of gaining the reference through a constructor parameter, and then calling a method on the variable that holds the reference in an event-driven setting.

Comment: i am so grateful from both you that you answered although the questions wasn't clear enough please pear with me because this is the first question for me on stackoverflow so i am still trying to know how to ask a proper question

Comment: so you mean that i should call the LF method by :  Tx_Customize.LF();

Comment: @FadyFarouk: Please see **Edit 3**

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and also your advice and i am sorry if i made any difficulties for you in understanding this part of my code

Comment: @FadyFarouk: are you doing this for school or for fun?

Comment: @FadyFarouk: for example, please check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693974/522444) of mine to see an example of getting a reference to another class and making method calls on it.

Comment: actually i 'm doing this for my graduation project as i am supposed to make the GUI of a program in order to visualize my results, my major is communication and electronics not computer and i attended a java course but they didn't get into details of the object oriented things

Comment: i want to ask a question @HoverCraftFullOfEels what is the main use of the reference because it is the first time for me to hear about it